# Couchbase - Full Eviction vs Value Eviction

Tags: spring-data, couchbase

How advantageous is Value Eviction over Full Eviction? In case of Value eviction , I assume meta-data is present in the RAM. How does presence of meta-data help in quicker retrieval of content? Is the NRU documents evicted high watermark is reached? Are there any aspects that we need to consider before changing the eviction policy from value eviction to full eviction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Value eviction keeps all document meta data in memory and full eviction does not.

Let's say you do a get on a key that does not exist. In value eviction mode you instantly know that the key is not there since it is a memory only operation. In full eviction mode if the meta data for that key is not in memory then you have to do a disk fetch to be sure that they key does not exist.

Basically any operation that requires knowledge of some information about a keys meta data may require a background fetch. Some other operations that may be slow if the meta data is not in memory are CAS set (check and set only if the value has not changed), appends, incrs, decrs, and prepends. Also keep in mind that extra disk activity may cause disk contention that affects other parts of Couchbase.

The NRU is the same across both full eviction and value eviction and Couchbase will do its best to keep your working set in memory.

I would recommend trying to get an idea of what your workload looks like before switching modes and test it out with full eviction because you may see performance issues with will vary depending on your workload.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Mike's answer it's worth mentioning bloom filters here which is a very powerful feature of Couchbase and can decrease the trips to disk significantly. Bloom filters are also enabled in value-only ejection but Couchbase really leverages their functionality in full ejection mode. I was in the situation where the system had reached its limit with value-only ejections buckets and I tested the two eviction modes and eventually the full ejection ended up being far superior - at least for my case.